# Create a permission AND set a role to it on module install

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, user-permissions

I've been looking for about an hour, and either I can't find it, or no one's asked this--which I would find odd.

I'd like my module, on install, to create a new role, create new permissions, and assign specific roles to the new permissions. What I seem to be getting hung up on is the last part.

I realize, conventionally, permissions are set in hook_permissions(), and I'm assuming by my sites behavior that hook_install() is called before those permissions are created (and that makes perfect sense.) So, my question is more than likely just:

> Is there a way to create permissions in the hook_install()/outside of hook_permissions()? I can't seem to find any examples of this, or any examples of setting permissions that don't already exist before module install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Features module can solve this problem for you, as you can export roles and permissions assigned to those roles.

The actual creating of the roles with permission happens when the module is enabled instead of when it's being installed, which is practially the same thing. Features allows you to export a lot of other things as well and is a really handy module.

Comment: Well, then would I be able to do the permission assignments on hook_enable? Or is that still too early.

Comment: @SlakeFistcrunch I believe it's possible, but I haven't tried doing it though.